# Why constructor does not work in some cases?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have a class definition. And I am confused about some constructor behaviour. Following is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class A
{
  int i;
public:
  void seti(int v) {cout << "Setting i\n"; i=v;}
  void print() {cout << "i = " << i << endl;}
  A(){};
  A(int v) {cout << "Setting i in par-ctor to " << v << "\n"; i=v;}
  A(A& o) {cout << "In copy ctor, changing i to " << o.i << "\n";i=o.i;}
  A& operator=(A o) {cout << "In assignment op\n"; this->i = o.i; return(*this);}
};

int main()
{
  A o1;
  A o2(2);
  A o3 = A(4);
  A o4 = 35;

  return(0);
}
```

I want to know why this code does not compile unless

a) The defined copy constructor is commented, or

b) The defined copy constructor has a `'const'` qualifier as in `A& A(const A& o)` or

c) Object initializations for both o3 and o4 are removed.

Regarding (c) in which the invocation of constructor A(int) is expected,

How does the actual copy constructor definition (the one without `const`) conflict with the parametrized (with int) constructor ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First look here:

```
A o3 = A(4);
```

The `A(4)` creates a temporary object. This expression is an rvalue. An rvalue cannot bind to a non-`const` lvalue reference like `A&`, so the copy constructor cannot be chosen. A better copy constructor declaration has a `const A&`, so that it can be constructed from rvalues too. That's why your (b) fix works.

The same problem manifests here:

```
A o4 = 35;
```

In copy-initialisation (with an `=`), a temporary of the object is constructed and then copied into the object you're declaring. So this is equivalent to:

```
A o4 = A(35);
```

And therefore exhibits the same problem as above.

Comment: @anupamb Don't forget to accept if you think it's right.